# Extract key value pairs from dict in pandas column using list items in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Trying to create a new column that is the key/value pairs extracted from a dict in another column using list items in a second column.

Sample Data:

```
names             name_dicts
['Mary', 'Joe']   {'Mary':123, 'Ralph':456, 'Joe':789}
```

Expected Result:

```
names             name_dicts                              new_col
['Mary', 'Joe']   {'Mary':123, 'Ralph':456, 'Joe':789}    {'Mary':123, 'Joe':789}
```

I have attempted to use AST to convert the name_dicts column to a column of true dictionaries.

This function errored out with a "cannot convert string" error.

**col** here is the **df['name_dicts']** col

```
def get_name_pairs(col):
    for k,v in col.items():
        if k.isin(df['names']):
            return
```

Comment: do you have string `"{'Mary':123, 'Ralph':456, 'Joe':789}"` in `name_dicts`?  It can make all problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a lambda function with dictionary comprehension at row level to get the values from the dict in second column based on the keys in the list of first column:

```py
# If col values are stored as string:
import ast
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['new_col']=df.apply(lambda x: {k:x['name_dicts'].get(k,0) for k in x['names']},
                         axis=1)

# Replace above lambda by
# lambda x: {k:x['name_dicts'][k] for k in x['names']  if k in x['name_dicts']}
# If you want to include only key/value pairs for the key that is in
# both the list and the dictionary

         names  ...                    new_col
0  [Mary, Joe]  ...  {'Mary': 123, 'Joe': 789}
[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

PS: `ast.literal_eval` runs without error for the sample data you have posted for above code.

Comment: Wow, thanks for responding so quickly.  I am going to run this now on my actual data.  I think you are correct that my data is throwing errors because of some missing items in the column itself.  Investigating that now.

Comment: This solution almost gets me there, but it is producing the actual key from the row in the dict column and the integer 0 as the value of every key.  Instead of producing the key/value pair from the dict column where the key is in the list of the names column.  Ideas?

Comment: that `0` is coming as default value from `..get(k,0)` and it is used as default value when item in the list is not present as a key in the dictionary

Comment: If you want to include the keys only if it is present in the dict, you may want to replace above lambda function by `lambda x: {k:x['name_dicts'][k] for k in x['names']} if k in x['name_dicts']` . Basically one extra check to see if the value is present as a key in the dictionary

Comment: Trying this function and it is giving me an underline at the last bracket.  Trying to see where a bracket is missing, but cannot figure that out.

Comment: My bad, a minor syntax error, the closing curly bracket should have been at last instead of before `if`: `lambda x: {k:x['name_dicts'][k] for k in x['names']  if k in x['name_dicts']}`

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

df['new_col'] = [dict(zip(l, itemgetter(*l)(d)))
                 for l,d in zip(df['names'], df['name_dicts'])]
```

output:

```
         names                               name_dicts                    new_col
0  [Mary, Joe]  {'Mary': 123, 'Ralph': 456, 'Joe': 789}  {'Mary': 123, 'Joe': 789}
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': [['Mary', 'Joe']],
                   'name_dicts': [{'Mary':123, 'Ralph':456, 'Joe':789}]
                  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs only small change - and you can use it with `.apply()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'names': [['Mary', 'Joe']],
    'name_dicts': [{'Mary':123, 'Ralph':456, 'Joe':789}],
})

def filter_data(row):
    result = {}
    for key, val in row['name_dicts'].items():
        if key in row['names']:
            result[key] = val
    return result

df['new_col'] = df.apply(filter_data, axis=1)

print(df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
         names                               name_dicts                    new_col
0  [Mary, Joe]  {'Mary': 123, 'Ralph': 456, 'Joe': 789}  {'Mary': 123, 'Joe': 789}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have string `"{'Mary':123, 'Ralph':456, 'Joe':789}"` in `name_dicts` then you can replace `'` with `"` and you will have `json` which you can convert to dictionary using `json.loads`

```
import json
df['name_dicts'] = df['name_dicts'].str.replace("'", '"').apply(json.loads)
```

Or directly convert it as Python's code:

```
import ast

df['name_dicts'] = df['name_dicts'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Eventually:

```
df['name_dicts'] = df['name_dicts'].apply(eval)
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'names': [['Mary', 'Joe']],
    'name_dicts': ["{'Mary':123, 'Ralph':456, 'Joe':789}",],  # strings
})

#import json
#df['name_dicts'] = df['name_dicts'].str.replace("'", '"').apply(json.loads)

#df['name_dicts'] = df['name_dicts'].apply(eval)

import ast
df['name_dicts'] = df['name_dicts'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

def filter_data(row):
    result = {}
    for key, val in row['name_dicts'].items():
        if key in row['names']:
            result[key] = val
    return result

df['new_col'] = df.apply(filter_data, axis=1)

print(df.to_string())
```